# Adding a value to the previous value using pyspark window function or pyspark sql

Tags: pyspark, lag

I have a dataset

```
+----+----+-------------------+
|orig|dest|   actl_dep_lcl_tms|
+----+----+-------------------+
| YYZ| YYR|2022-12-31 08:50:00|
| YYZ| YYR|2022-12-31 10:18:00|
| YYZ| YYR|2022-12-31 11:23:00|
+----+----+-------------------+
```

I want the output dataset as

```
+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|orig|dest|   actl_dep_lcl_tms|         Output_col|
+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| YYZ| YYR|2022-12-31 08:50:00|2022-12-31 08:50:00|
| YYZ| YYR|2022-12-31 10:18:00|2022-12-31 09:42:10|
| YYZ| YYR|2022-12-31 11:23:00|2022-12-31 11:53:00|
+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Output_col should start with minimum of the value and then add 15 minutes to the successive from the lagged value. Thanks